# Spray testkit doesn't seem to work for contentType

Tags: scala, spray

I have an example here: https://github.com/JoeCordingley/spray-marshallersExample where if you run the service then hit localhost:8080 with either application/json or application/myJson in the running service it returns the correct contentType but testing the route using spray testkit it always returns application/json. Am I using the testkit incorrectly or is there a fault in spray testkit?